# Python sqlite3 and matplotlib plot first graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, sqlite

I'm trying to plot my first graph with matplotlib, I'm new to sqlite3 and matplotlib and usually use rrdtool. I've no issue populating the database or retrieving (dumping) the database but I can't get my head around creating a graph. Can you put me on the right path to graphing a series of temperatures and humidity for my garage on a timeline?

The format of the table is:

```
create table external (temperature float, humidity float, feelslike float, timenow text);
```

An extract using .dump from the database looks like:

```
INSERT INTO "external" VALUES(17.0,68.0,11.6,'2017-07-24 12:24:02.578014');
INSERT INTO "external" VALUES(17.7,68.0,12.3,'2017-07-24 12:34:02.590939');
INSERT INTO "external" VALUES(17.7,68.0,12.3,'2017-07-24 12:44:02.585097');
INSERT INTO "external" VALUES(17.7,68.0,12.3,'2017-07-24 12:54:02.594123');
INSERT INTO "external" VALUES(18.3,63.0,12.8,'2017-07-24 13:04:02.586191');
INSERT INTO "external" VALUES(18.3,63.0,12.8,'2017-07-24 13:14:02.566619');
```

My function

```
import sqlite3
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from dateutil import parser
from matplotlib import style

def graph_data():
    # Connect to database
    now = datetime.now()
    sqlite_file = '/home/pi/scripts/database/climate.db'
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
    c = conn.cursor()
    style.use('fivethirtyeight')

    c.execute('SELECT temperature, humidity, feelslike, timenow FROM external')
    data = c.fetchall()

    temperature = []
    humidity = []
    feelslike = []
    timenow = []

    for row in data:
        timenow.append(parser.parse(row[0]))
        values.append(row[1])

    plt.plot_date(temperature, humidity, feelslike,'-')
    plt.savefig('/home/pi/scripts/database/foo.png')
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

My code is producing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 364, in <module>
    graph_data()
  File "test.py", line 323, in graph_data
    timenow.append(parser.parse(row[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1168, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 556, in parse
    res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 675, in _parse
    l = _timelex.split(timestr)         # Splits the timestr into tokens
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 192, in split
    return list(cls(s))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 61, in __init__
    '{itype}'.format(itype=instream.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not float
```

I'm guessing its the way its parsing the dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that [`sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) returns a (possibly empty) list of [`sqlite3.Row`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects) mappable/iterable objects, you just reversed the order - you try to parse temperature field as a date.
And your `values` variable is not defined.

Try this:

```
    c.execute('SELECT temperature, humidity, feelslike, timenow FROM external')
    data = c.fetchall()
    # data[*][0] = temperature
    # data[*][1] = humidity
    # data[*][2] = feelslike
    # data[*][3] = timenow

    temperature = []
    humidity = []
    feelslike = []
    timenow = []

    for row in data:
        temperature.append(row[0])
        humidity.append(row[1])
        feelslike.append(row[2])
        timenow.append(parser.parse(row[3]))
```

Additionally, as `Row` in addition to access by index also supports mapping access by column name, you could do:

```
    for row in data:
        temperature.append(row['temperature'])
        humidity.append(row['humidity'])
        feelslike.append(row['feelslike'])
        timenow.append(parser.parse(row['timenow']))
```

However access by index is faster and more efficient.

For plotting, you need to call `plot` multiple times, each time with the same x and different y data. For test, I generated my data set with:

```
    random.seed(0)
    data = [(random.uniform(10, 25),
             random.uniform(70, 99),
             random.uniform(15, 30),
             "2017-07-24 12:{:02d}:00.{:06d}".format(i, i * 1000 + int(random.uniform(0, 50)))
             ) for i in range(10)]
```

instead of using a database and `data = c.fetchall()`.

Now you have a set of `float` data points and associated `datetime.datetime` objects. However, `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date` function accepts:

> x and/or y can be a sequence of dates represented as float days since
>   0001-01-01 UTC.

To convert the date from `datetime.datetime` object to float days for matplotlib, function `matplotlib.dates.date2num` is used.

```
   for row in data:
       temperature.append(row[0])
       humidity.append(row[1])
       feelslike.append(row[2])
       timenow.append(parser.parse(row[3]))

   # Convert datetime.datetime to float days since 0001-01-01 UTC.
   dates = [date2num(t) for t in timenow]

   fig = plt.figure()
   ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
   ax1.set_title("My environmental data")

   # Configure x-ticks
   ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))

   # Plot temperature data on left Y axis
   ax1.set_ylabel("Temperature [°C]")
   ax1.plot_date(dates, temperature, '-', label="Temperature", color='r')
   ax1.plot_date(dates, feelslike, '-', label="Feels like", color='b')

   # Plot humidity data on right Y axis
   ax2 = ax1.twinx()
   ax2.set_ylabel("Humidity [% RH]")
   ax2.plot_date(dates, humidity, '-', label="Humidity", color='g')

   # Format the x-axis for dates (label formatting, rotation)
   fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=60)
   fig.tight_layout()

   # Show grids and legends
   ax1.grid(True)
   ax1.legend(loc='best', framealpha=0.5)
   ax2.legend(loc='best', framealpha=0.5)

   plt.savefig("figure.png")
```

This code produces the following image:
[image]

Comment: That works ! How do I go about plotting that data tho with multiple data against a timeline? This is clearly failing: `plt.plot_date(temperature, humidity, feelslike,'-')`

Comment: Thank you for a reminder, I did overlook that sentence. I edited the answer and added example of plotting.

Comment: Again that works really well and exactly what I was looking for to give me a working graph I can now learn from, build on and and tweak.